# Show that $\mu(E_a) \leq \frac{1}{a^p} \int_E |g|^pd \mu$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space, $E \subset \Omega$ and $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ are measurable. Let $E_a= \{x \in E \space | \space |g(x)| \geq a \}$ for $a>0$.

Show that for $p>0$: $$\mu(E_a) \leq \frac{1}{a^p} \int_E |g|^pd \mu \space .$$

---

It's probably not that difficult but I don't really know how to do it. I have a lot of similar problems, hopefully I can solve the others if I see one example.

Comment: $|g|^{p} I_{E_a}\geq a^{p} I_{E_a}$. Integrate.

Comment: Note that $\int_{E_a} |g|^p \le \int_{E} |g|^p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the hint given by Kavi, it is simple to see that:
$$a^p\mu(E_a) =\int\limits_{\Omega} \, a^p \mathbb{1}_{E_a} \, \mathrm{d} \mu  =\int\limits_{E} \, a^p \mathbb{1}_{E_a} \, \mathrm{d} \mu  \leq \int\limits_{
E} \,  |g|^p \mathbb{1}_{E_a} \, \mathrm{d} \mu \leq \int\limits_{E} \, |g|^p \, \mathrm{d} \mu $$
Then divide both sides by $a^p$ and then we are done